# Tcolorbox source outside of box

Tags: tcolorbox

How to insert source outside of boxes using tcolorbox, in my case box splitting as many pages.

[image]

MY MWE:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\RequirePackage{lipsum} 
\RequirePackage[breakable,hooks]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins} 
\makeatletter 
\newtcolorbox{Boxone}[2][]{% enhanced,
   boxrule=.2pt,boxsep=0pt,colframe=red,colback=gray, 
   enhanced,left=9pt,right=9pt,top=6pt,bottom=4pt, breakable,
   sharp corners, arc=15pt, rounded corners=northeast, 
   pad at break=9pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt, 
  %freelance,
  height fixed for=all, } 
\begin{document} 
\begin{Boxone}{Example 1.4} 
\lipsum[1-40] 
\end{Boxone} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please share the MWE!

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue. Instead real text simply use dummy text, for example by usage of package `lipsum` or `blindtext`. Then we can copy it and play on our computer with it to help you.

Comment: Yes, please find tex coding:  In this case footnote or source should be placed outside of box:

Comment: Footnotes are considered part of the textbox therefore are always included inside the `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Despite my previous comment, it's possible to add some text outside the box with overlays. You can see an example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454954/1952) (see updated section)

Comment: Yes, this answer is helpful to me, Thank you for your valuable information.

Comment: In tcolorbox how to set double column layout without using multicols environment, I assumed we set this as using raster column options, but not worked. Sorry for troubling which not identified before.